# Should we answer the passport-carrying question with a community wiki?

Tags: discussion

I am referring to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38944/when-travelling-do-i-have-to-keep-the-passport-with-me-all-the-time), regarding whether or not one should always carry some form of identification on oneself when travelling. Seeing as a universal answer cannot be produced, and seeing as answering this question would provide useful information for future reference, should we create a community wiki answer?

I think we could create one answer per continent, very much [like in this case](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11648/is-there-a-list-of-online-public-transportation-planners).

Comment: Would you accept a counter proposal? I.e., the set of documents that you should ALWAYS carry with you, of which the passport is one.  Nobody asked that specific question, but it's a magnitude more helpful...  Especially if the heavy-hitters weigh in...

Comment: @GayotFow should you always carry your passport with you though? It's a safety risk, so if there's no requirement that police can ask you for it, might it not be safer under lock and key at the hotel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly easier to manage the information, but from the point of view of someone looking for information about a specific country, it's not helpful to have to scroll down through a huge page of information, or even to have to follow another link to the section of the document that is pertinent to them.

Instead of merging many such questions into one question with a big answer or many answers, make a community wiki question with one community wiki answer and put links in the answer to each of the specific questions, like an index.

Comment: I actually think that finding all the information below one question is easier than having to search for each continent/country-specific question. That's the d reason i suggested the CW answer. Also, I'm afraid i didn't quite get your last paragraph. :)

Comment: It took me a few reads too, but I think he's saying make the CW answer an index, and you can link from it to individual questions which have the answers.

Comment: Not a bad idea, given we have several already that exist.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, if you want to create a universal one, or change the linked one into a more generic question and then answer with a CW answer, I think this could be a productive way to go.  We do however (I believe, but don't have time to find them right now) have this question already answered for some countries, so we'd have to consider what to do about that.

Comment: Is there a merge feature for questions on SE?

Comment: Yes, but you'd have to get one of the Travel Mods to handle it here.